# Optimize MLP Regression score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, mlp

I was trying to do a curve fit of a Langevin function using the MLPRegressor from the sklearn library but even using a test size of online **0.1** i cant get the **R^2** score above **0.97** so i would like to know if anyone could help me find a way to optimize the algorithm and the fit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import seaborn as sns
import numpy.random as rd

x_i = np.linspace(0.2,1,1000)
y_i = 1/np.tanh(x_i) - 1/x_i * 1.5 
#plt.plot(x_i,y_i,"o")
X_treino, X_teste, y_treino, y_teste = train_test_split(x_i.reshape(-1,1), y_i.reshape(-1,1) ,          test_size = 0.50)
model = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes = 200,activation = "relu" ,random_state = 1, max_iter = 200)
model.fit(X_treino, y_treino)
expected_y1  = y_teste
predicted_y1 = model.predict(X_teste)

print(metrics.r2_score(expected_y1, predicted_y1))

plt.figure(figsize = (16,9))
plt.plot(X_teste,y_teste,"o", color = "red", label = "Esperado")
plt.plot(X_teste,predicted_y1,"o", color = "blue", label = "Previsto")
plt.legend(fontsize = "large")
```

Comment: Tune hidden layers sizes and max iteration parameters.

Comment: I adjusted them but for 20k plus max iterations and 200 hidden layers there was no change on the result

Comment: Try `(hidden_layer_sizes = 2048,activation = "relu" ,random_state = 1, max_iter = 512)`, also test_size as 0.2 is sufficient

Comment: it gives a 0.98 R^2